Supabase Private Schema - Returned Nulled Error
I'm confused as i cant figure out the settings required for me to insert into private schema from javascript , both my tables in public and private has the same structure and I'm already using service keys but still getting Error upserting into Supabase: {} which from my understanding it's returning null because my service keys has no permission?
The upsert is working perfect for public schema, just not the private schema.
async function sendToSupabase(details) {
      const supabaseUrl = 'https://xx.supabase.co';
      const supabaseKey = 'xx';
      const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey);
    
      try {
        const { data, error } = await supabase
          .from('private.events')
          .upsert([
            {
              title: details.title,
            }
          ], { onConflict: 'title' });
    
        if (error) {
          console.error('Error upserting into Supabase:', error);
        } else {
          console.log('Upserted into Supabase:', data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in Supabase operation:', error.message);
      }
    }

Their documentation is lacking when it comes to using private schema and if anyone could provide any tips of guide , that would be greatly appreciated.
Things i've tried

Row Level Security disabled

Creating a policy for service_role when RLS is enabled



